# How to identify the query that is making the Compute utilization reaches 100% DTU

Tags: azure-sql-database

Running a load test the DTU of Azure SQL Database goes to 100% (Standard S2: 50 DTUs).

How Can I identify which query is causing this?  but the queries have low DTU usage. This can be seen in picture 1 below.

In the CPU, I can see that it is still low img 2.

Is the query in image 3 that is making the DTU reaches 100%?

The point is that I do not want to increase the DTU without making sure the queries as optimized.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it the query **5668**.

The query doesn't have low CPU usage. Is on 50% average and spikes up at 100%:

[image]

The query **5668** is the guilty one. You can see it because is the red color on the stack an it's the one who is taking more CPU compared to the others:

[image]

Test it by running it yourself. If it gets executed in seconds think about if it's executed multiple times.